# Determine whether $\{A_{\alpha} \cap B: \alpha \in I\}$ is a partition of $B \subseteq X$, where $\{A_{\alpha}: \alpha \in I\}$ partitions $X$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let $X$ be a nonempty set, and $\{A_{\alpha}: \alpha \in I\}$ be a partition of $X$. Further, let $B \subseteq X$, such that $A_{\alpha} \cap B \neq \emptyset$ for all $\alpha \in I$. Is $\{A_{\alpha} \cap B: \alpha \in I\}$ a partition of $B$?

*Proof*: We must show that all the sets are nonempty, that their union equals $B$, and any two of the sets are disjoint or equal.

1. We are given that all $A_{\alpha} \cap B$ are non-empty.
2. $\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} (A_{\alpha} \cap B) = \left ( \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_{\alpha} \right ) \cap B = X \cap B = B$. (The first equality is a set identity; the second follows from the assumption that $\{A_{\alpha}: \alpha \in I\}$ partitions $X$; and the final equality follows from an already-proven theorem, since $B \subseteq X$.)
3. Let $\alpha, \beta \in I$ with $(A_{\alpha} \cap B) \cap (A_{\beta} \cap B) \neq \emptyset$, which we can write as $(A_{\alpha} \cap A_{\beta}) \cap B \neq \emptyset$. So $A_{\alpha} \cap A_{\beta} \neq \emptyset$, and since $\{A_{\alpha}: \alpha \in I\}$ is a partition, $A_{\alpha} = A_{\beta}$. So $A_{\alpha} \cap B = A_{\beta} \cap B$, as desired.

I am most unsure about the last step.

Comment: It is easier to show that for $\alpha, \beta\in I$ with $\alpha\neq \beta$ we have $$ (A_\alpha \cap B )\cap (A_\beta \cap B)= (A_\alpha\cap A_\beta)\cap B =\emptyset \cap B=\emptyset.$$

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point. Is what I'd done otherwise correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. My remark was just a stylistic one :)